# Energy of a color image

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to calculate the energy of an RGB image by summing up the squares of pixel values (i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^{W}\sum_{j=1}^{H}(R^2+B^2+G^2)$). I was wondering if this is the right way to calculate the energy of a color image. I found literature on calculating the energy of a grayscale image but not for a color image. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Images don't have energy as far as I know. Where have you encountered this terminology? Can you share some references?

Comment: What's the _definition_ of the "energy" of an image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562801/what-is-energy-in-image-processing